# in javascript, cannot replace() using a sub-match

Tags: javascript, regex

wish to escape all occurrences of "." and ":" within square brackets

```
[ab:1.2:ef]='12.3' => [ab\:1\.2\:ef]='12.3'
```

tried various permutations on `replace`, eg,

```
str.replace( /(\[.*)(\.|:)(.*\])/g, '\1\\\2\3' );
```

but no joy.

---

Both answers correct and more.

The first, a pure pattern match, does the job and is very succinct.  In my opinion it answers the stated question better.

The second, calling `replace` with a function arg, is a wee bit more robust and offers considerably more flexibility.  In my code using this approach because it handles a couple of special cases easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the brackets are always correctly balanced (even within strings or comments) and can never be nested or escaped, you can solve this in a single regex using [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
result = subject.replace(/([:.])(?=[^[\]]*\])/g, "\\$1");
```

As a commented regex:

```
([:.])    # Match and remember a dot/colon,
(?=       # only if it is followed by:
 [^[\]]*  # any number of characters excluding brackets,
 \]       # followed by a closing bracket.
)         # End of lookahead assertion.
```

The lookahead ensures that the next bracket after the dot/colon we're looking at is a closing bracket.

Comment: great explanation.  took me by surprise that you're not worrying about the leading bracket (since it has to be there) - makes the matching less complex.

Comment: This doesn't require both opening and closing brace.  Thus, it doesn't work for: `[ab:1.2:ef]='12.3]'` or `ab:1.2:ef]='12.3'`.

Comment: Right, that's why I wrote that the brackets must be correctly balanced (JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions). I should add that this also concerns brackets inside strings, comments etc.

Answer (score 1):

I only know how to do it with a replace function:

```
var test = "[ab:1.2:ef]='12.3'";

var out = test.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, function(str) {
    return(str.replace(/\.|:/g, "\\$&"));
});

// out is [ab\:1\.2\:ef]='12.3'
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ZHVjW/

Comment: wow! have never seen a function used as the argument in `replace` - very cool.  much more elegant than the `match` loop was using before.  thanks!

Comment: Concerning your comment to my answer, your regex will also have problems with unbalanced brackets in strings like `[ab:1.2] = '[12.3'; [cd:3.4] = '34.5]'`. As soon as delimiters are unbalanced and/or inside strings/comments, regexes start to fail, and you need a parser for this kind of job.

Comment: Yes, fine line between getting job done and bring out the big iron.  That said, do you know of a utility that will transform a (somewhat) arbitrary string into polish-type tree structure?

Comment: @TimPietzcker - the example you point out is nested brackets.  The OP didn't specify that nested brackets were a requirement.  The solution for nested would be much more complicated (probably not just a regex problem) with either approach.  I just thought it odd that your solution doesn't require an opeing bracket of any kind.  If the OP is OK with that, no big deal.

Comment: Which nested brackets? Those would have been an additional problem (for all of our regexes); here there's just brackets inside strings. The problem would have remained identical with `[ab:1.2] = '[12.3'; [cd:3.4] = '34.5'`.